# Tag template wordpress: cluster by category title

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, tags, categories

I am modifying the tag template (tag.php) in Wordpress. I would like to display a list of posts, grouped by category name.

This is the code which allows me to group the posts by tag. Could it be modified in order to group by category title?

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts(array(
   'post_type'      => 'post',
   'category'       => $cat_id,
   'tag'            => $tag->slug,
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'meta_key'       => 'title',
   'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
   'order'          => 'ASC'
));

if ( $posts ): ?>
   <?php echo '<h3 style="margin-top: 1em;"> <a style="color: black;" id="' .
   $tag->name . '">' . $tag->name . '</a></h3>'; ?>
```

Comment: I assume you want to group your posts by *category* AND also *tag*, right? Because if it's only by category then use `category.php` instead of `tag.php`

Comment: The tag template in Wordpress is used to list all the contents which includes a specific tag (meaning that on the page mywebsite.com/tag/mytag I see a list of posts which are tagged with "mytag"). What I would like to do, is to group the posts in this list in order to visualise them by the category they belong to.